# how to re structuring my existing function as my data set get changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

earlier my dataset is like

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds']})
```

i.e.
[image]

so to perform some alteration I  have created a function
which is as follows

```
def df_refactor(df, x, y):  # x=>column label which I want to rename with y
    df.rename(columns={x: y}, inplace=True)
    df.set_index(y, drop=True, inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return df
```

so to call the function I am using df_refactor(df, a, y)
but now my data set is changed i.e.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','mqr','sas','ho']})
```

[image]

now I wanted to use the same function and want to change the both the column header i.e. a => m and b=> n so what change do I need to do on my function so that I can re utilized the same funcion

Comment: Why not just call your function twice,  once with 'a', 'm' and again for 'b', 'n'?

Comment: because I wanted to perform the operation in a single go

Comment: you can create a new function that takes a list of [old_name, new_name] pairs and the new function iterates through that list of pairs, calling the old function each time.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this is the solution of your problem:

```
def df_refactor(df, x: list, y: list):  # x=>column label which I want to rename with y
    columns = dict(zip(x, y))
    df.rename(columns=columns, inplace=True)
    df.set_index(y, drop=True, inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return df
```

some example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc','pqr','ss','sd','sds'], 'b':['sdd','gbc','mqr','sas','ho']})
df_refactor(df1,  ['a', 'b'], ['m', 'n'])
```

Also this [link](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-dataframe-rename/#:%7E:text=DataFrame.-,rename(),any%20row%20%2F%20column%20name%20individually.&text=Specify%20the%20original%20name%20and,index%20%2F%20columns%20of%20rename()%20.) may be useful.